# Class wrapper around file -- proper way to close file handle when no longer referenced

Tags: garbage-collection, python, resource-cleanup

I've got a class that wraps some file handling functionality I need. Another class creates an instance of the `filehandler` and uses it for an indeterminate amount of time. Eventually, the `caller` is destroyed, which destroys the only reference to the `filehandler`.

What is the best way to have the `filehandler` close the file?

I currently use `__del__(self)` but after seeing [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7888953/guaranteeing-a-file-close) [different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2404430/does-filehandle-get-closed-automatically-in-python-after-it-goes-out-of-scope) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6104535/i-dont-understand-this-python-del-behaviour) [and articles](http://excess.org/article/2011/12/unfortunate-python/), I'm under the impression this is considered **a bad thing**.

```
class fileHandler:
    def __init__(self, dbf):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('fileHandler')
        self.thefile = open(dbf, 'rb')
    def __del__(self):
        self.thefile.close()
```

That's the relevent bit of the handler. The whole point of the class is to abstract away details of working with the underlying file object, and also to avoid reading the entire file into memory unnecessarily. However, part of handling the underlying file is closing it when the object falls out of scope.

The `caller` is not supposed to know or care about the details involved in the `filehandler`. It is the `filehandler`'s job to release any necessary resources involved when it falls out of scope. That's one of the reasons it was abstracted in the first place. So, I seem to be faced with moving the `filehandler` code into the calling object, or dealing with a leaky abstraction.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`__del__` is not, by itself, a bad thing.  You just have to be extra careful to not create reference cycles in objects that have `__del__` defined.  If you do find yourself needing to create cycles (parent refers to child which refers back to parent) then you will want to use the `weakref` module.

So, `__del__` is okay, just be wary of cyclic references.

Garbage collection:  The important point here is that when an object goes out of scope, it *can* be garbage collected, and in fact, it *will* be garbage collected... but when?  There is no guarantee on the when, and different Python implementations have different characteristics in this area.  So for managing resources, you are better off being explicit and either adding `.close()` on your `filehandler` or, if your usage is compatible, adding `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods.

The [`__enter__` and `__exit__` methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html?highlight=__enter__#object.__enter__) are described here.  One really nice thing about them is that `__exit__` is called even when exceptions occur, so you can count or your resources being closed gracefully.

Your code, enhanced for `__enter__`/`__exit__`:

```
class fileHandler:
    def __init__(self, dbf):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('fileHandler')
        self.thefilename = dbf
    def __enter__(self):
        self.thefile = open(self.thefilename, 'rb')
        return self
    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.thefile.close()
```

Note that the file is being opened in `__enter__` instead of `__init__` -- this allows you to create the file handler object once, and then use it whenever you need to in a `with` without recreating it:

```
fh = filehandler('some_dbf')
with fh:
    #file is now opened
    #do some stuff
#file is now closed
#blah blah
#need the file again, so
with fh:
    # file is open again, do some stuff with it
#etc, etc
```

Comment: Nice trick with opening the file in `__enter__()` -- you could also do some magic in there to retain the file position between opens/closes.

Comment: Very nice, this is much closer to what I wanted. The ref cycles is the first thing I checked for, and I don't have any. But some articles say that whole object chains will be noncollectable if a leaf object has a del method, regardless of ref cycles.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun: All the documentation I have been able to find states the items are uncollectible **only if** there are ref cycles.

Comment: While it isn't exactly what I wanted, it'll do the job. I'm accepting your answer.

Comment: @SpencerRathbun:  I omitted adding `.close`,`open`, and `__del__` methods as it would have complicated my example (and I thought opening the file in `__enter__` was a cool trick ;) but you can certainly add them back in, and then you can use the `filehandler` in whichever way makes sense at the time.  Keep in mind, though, the lack of time gaurantees when using `__del__`.

Comment: Why do you have *args in __exit__(self, *args):?

Comment: @NiekdeKlein: Because `__exit__` actually takes three other arguments (Exception info if one occured, or None three times) but I don't need them named since the code will not be doing anything different:  possibility 1) exception occured -- result -> close the file; possibility 2) no exception occured -- result -> close the file.

Answer (score 8):

As you've written it the class doesn't make the file close any more reliably. If you simple drop the filehandler instance on the floor then the file won't close until the object is destroyed. This might be immediately or might not be until the object is garbage collected, but just dropping a plain file object on the floor would close it just as quickly. If the only reference to `thefile` is from inside your class object then when `filehandler` is garbage collected `thefile` will be also be garbage collected and therefore closed at the same time.

The correct way to use files is to use the `with` statement:

```
with open(dbf, 'rb') as thefile:
    do_something_with(thefile)
```

that will guarantee that `thefile` is always closed whenever the `with` clause exits. If you want to wrap your file inside another object you can do that too by defining `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods:

```
class FileHandler:
    def __init__(self, dbf):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger('fileHandler')
        self.thefile = open(dbf, 'rb')
    def __enter__(self):
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.thefile.close()
```

and then you can do:

```
with FileHandler(dbf) as fh:
    do_something_with(fh)
```

and be sure the file gets closed promptly.